# Unable to parse json event with nested avro schema

Tags: java, avro

I am trying to produce a Kafka event with Avro schema but failed to produce event due to avro format. I have also tried generating random data with avro format but could not parse generated random event data too.

**My Avro schema is:**

```
{
  "type":"record",
  "name":"CsrGlobalSchema",
  "namespace":"com.ibm.csr",
  "fields":[
    {
      "name":"data",
      "type":[
        {
          "type":"record",
          "name":"data",
          "namespace":"com.ibm.csr.data",
          "fields":[
            {
              "name":"entId",
              "type":[
                "string",
                "null"
              ]
            },
            {
              "name":"device",
              "type":[
                {
                  "type":"record",
                  "name":"device",
                  "namespace":"com.ibm.csr.data.device",
                  "fields":[
                    {
                      "name":"appName",
                      "type":[
                        "string",
                        "null"
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      "name":"id",
                      "type":[
                        "string",
                        "null"
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      "name":"name",
                      "type":[
                        "string",
                        "null"
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                },
                "null"
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "null"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name":"evtCxt",
      "type":[
        {
          "type":"record",
          "name":"evtCxt",
          "fields":[
            {
              "name":"action",
              "type":[
                "string",
                "null"
              ]
            },
            {
              "name":"evtSubType",
              "type":[
                "string",
                "null"
              ]
            },
            {
              "name":"evtTs",
              "type":[
                "long",
                "null"
              ]
            },
            {
              "name":"evtType",
              "type":[
                "string",
                "null"
              ]
            },
            {
              "name":"srcEvtId",
              "type":[
                "string",
                "null"
              ]
            },
            {
              "name":"type",
              "type":[
                "string",
                "null"
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "null"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name":"glbCxt",
      "type":[
        {
          "type":"record",
          "name":"glbCxt",
          "fields":[
            {
              "name":"tntId",
              "type":[
                "string",
                "null"
              ]
            },
            {
              "name":"tntName",
              "type":[
                "string",
                "null"
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "null"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**My Event data in JSON format is:**

```
{
  "data":{
    "entId":"adfdf"
  },
  "evtCxt":{
    "srcEvtId":"095d895e-595a-40a0-a887-dd158a3b383e",
    "evtTs":10202002002,
    "evtType": "EntityCreation",
    "evtSubType": "devAppCompliance",
    "type":"device",
    "action":"create"
  },
  "glbCxt":{
    "tntId":"663f4d7b",
    "tntName":"11111222"
  }
}
```

I tried generating random data using below code:

```
InputStream is = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("global_event_schema_expanded.avsc");
            Schema schema = new Schema.Parser().parse(is);
            Iterator<Object> it = new RandomData(schema, 4).iterator();
            System.out.println(it.next());
```

But still Avro schema is unable to parse the random data as well.

My code to parse event data and generate event is:

```
            String schemaStr = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("global_event_schema_expanded.avsc")));
            String genericRecordStr = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("kafka_event_data_create.json")));

            Schema.Parser parser = new Schema.Parser();
            Schema schema = parser.parse(schemaStr);

            GenericRecord genericRecord = new GenericData.Record(schema);
            genericRecord.put("data", genericRecordStr);
            ProducerRecord<String, Object> record = new ProducerRecord<String, Object>("source-data-topic", "data", genericRecord);
            try {
                final Future<RecordMetadata> send = producer.send(record);
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
                producer.flush();
                producer.close();
            }
```

I have tried JsonDecoder as well.

```
            String schemaStr = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("global_event_schema_expanded.avsc")));
            String genericRecordStr = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("kafka_event_data_create.json")));
            Schema.Parser schemaParser = new Schema.Parser();
            Schema schema = schemaParser.parse(schemaStr);
            DecoderFactory decoderFactory = new DecoderFactory();
            Decoder decoder = decoderFactory.jsonDecoder(schema, genericRecordStr);
            DatumReader<GenericData.Record> reader =
                    new GenericDatumReader<>(schema);
            GenericRecord genericRecord = reader.read(null, decoder);

            ProducerRecord<String, Object> record = new ProducerRecord<String, Object>("source-data-topic", "data", genericRecord);
            try {
                final Future<RecordMetadata> send = producer.send(record);
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
                producer.flush();
                producer.close();
            }
```

Comment: 1) Please show your RandomData class 2) Avro has a JSONDecoder class that you might want to be using, otherwise, the data you're sending is just a record with a string field `data`, **not** a `CsrGlobalSchema` type... Why aren't you using the Avro maven plugin?

Comment: @OneCricketeer 1) org.apache.avro.util.RandomData - This is the random data class I have used.2) Updated question with JsonDecoder code snippet I had tried.

Comment: Thanks. Still - why not generate a SpecificRecord type using Maven and your AVSC file? And what specific errors are you getting?